# Как добавить аргументы в функцию

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы `select` принимал в функции `query()` в переменной `result` результат функции `filterIn()` и фильтровал по своим аргументам `'name'`, `'gender'`, `'email'`. Не пойму как передать в `select()` эти аргументы `'name'`, `'gender'`, `'email'`.

```
var friends = [
    {
        name: 'Сэм',
        gender: 'Мужской',
        email: 'luisazamora@example.com',
        favoriteFruit: 'Картофель'
    },
    {
        name: 'Эмили',
        gender: 'Женский',
        email: 'example@example.com',
        favoriteFruit: 'Яблоко'
    },
    {
        name: 'Мэт',
        gender: 'Мужской',
        email: 'danamcgee@example.com',
        favoriteFruit: 'Яблоко'
    },
    {
        name: 'Брэд',
        gender: 'Мужской',
        email: 'newtonwilliams@example.com',
        favoriteFruit: 'Банан'
    }
];

function query(collection) {
    var result = select(arguments[2]);
    return result;
};

function select() {
    var selectArr = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        for (var key in friends[i]) {
            if (selectArr.indexOf.call(arguments, key) == -1) {
              delete selectArr[i][key];
            }
        }
    }
    return selectArr
};

function filterIn(property, values) {
    var arr = [];
        for (var q = 0; q < friends.length; q++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                if (friends[q].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    if (friends[q][property] == values[i]) {
                        arr.push(friends[q])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
};

var lib = query(friends, select('name', 'gender', 'email'), filterIn('favoriteFruit', ['Яблоко', 'Картофель']));
console.log(lib)
```

Результат вывести должен такой.

```
[
    { name: 'Сэм', gender: 'Мужской', email: 'luisazamora@example.com' },
    { name: 'Эмили', gender: 'Женский', email: 'example@example.com' },
    { name: 'Мэт', gender: 'Мужской', email: 'danamcgee@example.com' },
    { name: 'Шерри', gender: 'Женский', email: 'danamcgee@example.com' },
    { name: 'Стелла', gender: 'Женский', email: 'waltersguzman@example.com' }
]
```

Comment: лучше бы вы это все в виде класса с методами реализовали а не отдельных функций, тогда и вопросов не будет, как в одном методе использовать результаты другого, ибо можно здесь же хранить промежуточные результаты

Comment: Ну это не я так сделал, а была дана задача и эти три функции

Comment: Кто есть `friends`?

Comment: кто-то вообще понял вопрос? %) зачем там `arguments` если аргументы заданы явно?

Comment: если вам нужно отфильтровать массив объектов и выбрать только нужные поля, это можно написать в 1 строчку в таком виде, что другие программисты в будующем поймут , что вообще имелось в виду

Comment: @АлександрПупкин Откуда в результате возьмется "Стелла", если ее нет в исходном `friends`?

Comment: Я понимаю это, но в задаче нужно чтобы было три функции, в первой выполняется filterIn() и ее значение передается в select(), а она в свою очередь возвращает конечный результат своей фильтрации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по описанию и примеру вызова функция `query` должна принимать три параметра, а не один, как сейчас. И в общем виде ее можно записать так:

```
function query(collection, selectFunc, filterFunc){
    return collection.filter(filterFunc).map(selectFunc);
}
```

Для этой функции осталось получить нужные функции.

Пускай `filterIn` будет возвращать функцию, принимающую объект, и возвращающую `true` если объект удовлетворяет условию и `false` в противном случае.

Условие можно писать так: указанное поле, должно иметь одно из перечисленных значений.

Тогда `filterIn` может принять следующий вид:

```
function filterIn(field, allowedValues){
    return function filterFunc(element) {
        return allowedValues.includes(element[field]);
    };
}
```

Теперь к функции `select`, по переданным полям нужно собрать объект включающий только эти поля. Реализовать это можно с помощью [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
function select(...fields){
    return function selectFunc(element) {
        return fields.reduce((acc,fieldName)=>{
            acc[fieldName] = element[fieldName];
            return acc;
        },{});
    };
}
```

Пример в сборе:

```js
var friends = [{
    name: 'Сэм',
    gender: 'Мужской',
    email: 'luisazamora@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Картофель'
  },
  {
    name: 'Эмили',
    gender: 'Женский',
    email: 'example@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Яблоко'
  },
  {
    name: 'Мэт',
    gender: 'Мужской',
    email: 'danamcgee@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Яблоко'
  },
  {
    name: 'Брэд',
    gender: 'Мужской',
    email: 'newtonwilliams@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Банан'
  }
];

function query(collection, selectFunc, filterFunc) {
  return collection.filter(filterFunc).map(selectFunc);
}

function filterIn(field, allowedValues) {
  return function filterFunc(element) {
    return allowedValues.includes(element[field]);
  };
}


function select(...fields) {
  return function selectFunc(element) {
    return fields.reduce((acc, fieldName) => {
      acc[fieldName] = element[fieldName];
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };
}

var lib = query(friends, select('name', 'gender', 'email'), filterIn('favoriteFruit', ['Яблоко', 'Картофель']));
console.log(lib)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ)